# JSON data ajax is not POST data correctly

Tags: php, json, ajax

i am trying to POST some JSON data in PHP. But something is wrong.

This is my html --

```
<tbody>
    {% for x in sets %}
        <tr class="">
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {% if x is defined %}{{x}}</div>{% else %}{% endif %}
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" class ="first" name ="first"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class ="second" name ="second"></td>
            <td><span id="txtData"></span></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

and this is my script

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#scoreForm").on('submit', function (e) {
            $("#submit").show();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            data['first'] = $('#first').val();
            data['second'] = $('#second').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/processdata',
                type: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Frames : data }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (returnedData) {
```

So when i POST the data it look like so ---

[image]

what i want is that when i post the data ---

```
["frames": {"first":6, "second": 7}, {"first": 4, "second": 9}]
```

Do anyone knows where i am making the mistake !
Any advice will be really really appreciable ...

Comment: You shouldn't use IDs for this, an ID should be unique. You need to use classes.

Comment: @Styphon how should i do that, can you kindly show me an example please if possible

Comment: `<td><input type="number" CLASS="first" name ="first"></td>
            <td><input type="number" CLASS="second" name ="second"></td>` Change the ID to Class (I've capitalised it so you can see it easier. Then change your javascript to loop through each element and save it in the array.

Comment: @Styphon thanks a lot, you are awesome

Comment: @Styphon sorry , but using the class also returning the exact same results !

Comment: Don't stringify your data when passing into php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var data = $(this).serialize();
> ```

This converts the form data to a string.

> ```
> data['first'] = $('#first').val();
> data['second'] = $('#second').val();
> ```

This then tries to add properties to the string, but only for the first match for each element in the DOM.

---

The simple solution to this is **don't use JSON**.

1. Get rid of the id attributes in your inputs. Duplicate ids are forbidden.
2. Change the names to end in `[]` to deal with PHP's unique form handling system
3. Get rid of all the lines like `data['first'] = $('#first').val();`
4. Change `data: JSON.stringify({ Frames : data }),` to `data: data`
5. Get rid of `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`
6. Change your PHP to read directly from `$_POST` instead of expecting a JSON formatted request

---

If you really want to use JSON, then you need to build the data structure yourself.

You'll also find it more work to make your form [work properly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) when [JS fails](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

> ["frames": {"first":6, "second": 7}, {"first": 4, "second": 9}]

… but that isn't valid JSON.

You'd need something more like:

```
{"frames": [ {"first":6, "second": 7}, {"first": 4, "second": 9} ]}
```

1. Get rid of the id attributes in your inputs. Duplicate ids are forbidden.
2. Get rid of all thee of the lines I quoted at the top of this answer
3. Get the form data

   1. Create an array (`var data = []`)
   2. Get the table rows: `var rows = jQuery('tr')` is a start, but you'll probably want to be more specific
   3. For each row get the data you want and add it to the array: `rows.each(function () { data.push({ first: jQuery(this).find("[name=first]").val(), second: jQuery(this).find("[name=second]").val() });`